# Is high variation in the independent variable desirable?

Tags: regression, econometrics

Is the following claim true/false in a regression model?

A high variation in the independent variable and a large sample size are desirable because the improve the precision with which the parameters are estimated.

I know that the second part of the claim is true but how about the first one?

Comment: I don't know--what exactly do you mean by "high variation"?  Sample size is often something under your control, but in what sense do you intend to control "variation" in independent variables? Are you talking about an experimental setup? If, as is almost always the case in econometrics, you are considering an observational study, then how do you conceive of controlling or influencing this variation?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that high variation in the predictor variables lead to greater precision of the parameters. Take this to mean high variance in the independent variables leads to lower variance of the parameter.

This is visible from the standard error formula of the parameters, in the simple least squares(one independent variable), the standard error of the intercept is given by:

$\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}  \sqrt{1+\frac{\bar{x}^{2}}{var(x)}}$   where $s$ is the standard error of the regression.

Inside the square root, a higher variance of $x$ would lower the value of the square root which results in lower standard error of the intercept estimate. The same is true for the other parameter using its standard error formula:

$\frac{s}{n}  \sqrt{\frac{1}{sdev(x)}}$

For the multivariable regression case, this relation still holds but is harder to see in the matrix form of the parameters' variance:

$\sigma^{2}({X}'X)^{-1}$

See formulas [here](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/mathreg.htm).

Comment: And D-optimal experimental design is exploiting this. If you want an D-optimal design for a regression model with only one $x$ variable, which can be controlled in the interval $L,U$, then the design will place half of observations at $x=L$ and half at $x=U$.  That might not be desirable if you want to be able to test the assumption about linearity in $x$!